# Storing values from API and then getting data to reduce amount of requests

Tags: javascript, api, local-storage, storage

The following code takes data from an API, however I want to store the data and then take values from the stored data if possible. I have no idea how to do this and was hoping someone could at least point me in the right direction. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
let arrivalUrl = "https://aerodatabox.p.rapidapi.com/flights/airports/icao/egnx/" + YYYY + "-" + MM + "-" + DD + "T" + HH + ":" + Mins + "/" + YYYY + "-" + MM + "-" + DD + "T" + HH2 + ":" + Mins2 + "?rapidapi-key=88ba89e474mshf44d973b69b2a4cp1dacdfjsnac365a6da71e";

function getArrivalInfo() {
    dataObject3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    dataObject3.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    });
    dataObject3.open('GET', arrivalUrl, true);
    dataObject3.send();
    dataObject3.onload = function() {
        ArrivalInfo = JSON.parse(dataObject3.responseText);

        // 1st Arrival.
        document.getElementById('arrivalairport0').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[0].movement.airport.icao;
        document.getElementById('arrivaltime0').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[0].movement.scheduledTimeLocal.substring(11, 16);
        document.getElementById('arrivalcallsign0').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[0].number;
        document.getElementById('arrivalstatus0').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[0].status;
        document.getElementById('arrivalaircraft0').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[0].aircraft.model;
        // 2nd Arrival.
        document.getElementById('arrivalairport1').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[1].movement.airport.icao;
        document.getElementById('arrivaltime1').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[1].movement.scheduledTimeLocal.substring(11, 16);
        document.getElementById('arrivalcallsign1').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[1].number;
        document.getElementById('arrivalstatus1').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[1].status;
        document.getElementById('arrivalaircraft1').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[1].aircraft.model;
        // 3rd Arrival.
        document.getElementById('arrivalairport2').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[2].movement.airport.icao;
        document.getElementById('arrivaltime2').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[2].movement.scheduledTimeLocal.substring(11, 16);
        document.getElementById('arrivalcallsign2').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[2].number;
        document.getElementById('arrivalstatus2').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[2].status;
        document.getElementById('arrivalaircraft2').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[2].aircraft.model;
        // 4th Arrival.
        document.getElementById('arrivalairport3').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[3].movement.airport.icao;
        document.getElementById('arrivaltime3').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[3].movement.scheduledTimeLocal.substring(11, 16);
        document.getElementById('arrivalcallsign3').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[3].number;
        document.getElementById('arrivalstatus3').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[3].status;
        document.getElementById('arrivalaircraft3').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[3].aircraft.model;
        // 5th Arrival.
        document.getElementById('arrivalairport4').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[4].movement.airport.icao;
        document.getElementById('arrivaltime4').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[4].movement.scheduledTimeLocal.substring(11, 16);
        document.getElementById('arrivalcallsign4').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[4].number;
        document.getElementById('arrivalstatus4').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[4].status;
        document.getElementById('arrivalaircraft4').innerHTML = ArrivalInfo.arrivals[4].aircraft.model;
    }
}
getArrivalInfo();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "store the data and then take values from the stored data"?

Comment: Well I just need to be able to store the data and then use the stored data in my html page if that’s possible. The aim is to make it so that I am not taking as many requests to the API servers. Preferably I would have new api data taken every hour or so however I need to get the basic storing element first. Could I create a database somehow?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to implement caching. This might help: https://dev.to/adancarrasco/caching-api-requests-in-javascript-mc4

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you exactly want to do, but I believe you want to reduce the number of round trips to the server and improve the response time.

One possible way is to cache the data. Read this article; it can help. **https://medium.com/javascript-dots/cache-api-in-javascript-644380391681**